# Is it possible to performSegue from the UIView XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, xib

In my ViewController I set:

```
self.view.addSubview(xib)
```

where `xib` is a `class myView: UIView {`

Can I perform segue when a user clicks on a button from those XIB? Because when I try, it says that

```
Value of type myView has no member performSegue
```

What is another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve using protocols/delegates.

In you UIView class have a protocol with method for example : `userDidClickButton()`

And in your viewController class listen to the delegate call back.
When you create the instance of you UIView class assign the delegate to self example:
 `uiviewClassInstance.delegate = self`

And in your view controller class implement the above delegate method and inside it call `perfromSegue`.

Edit:
 inside your UIView class

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    // protocol definition goes here
    func didClickSubmit()
}

var delegate:SomeProtocol



@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.didClickSubmit() 
  }
```

View controller class:

```
public class YourViewController: UIViewController,SomeProtocol

let signUpView = SignUpView.signUpView()
singUpView.delegate = self

func didClickSubmit() {
     // Perform your segue here
}
```

Comment: `let signUpView = SignUpView.signUpView()` it does not have a delegate method

Comment: can you please write it in Gist?

Comment: This answer is correct, the reason you get the does not have delegate error method is because you haven't linked your UIView class to your UIViewController as an instance - or you have and are not using the instance as your "instance.delegate = self"

Comment: Follow-up to the above comment: To link it all you need to do is go to your storyboard, and right click the view and drag onto your view controller code (via assistant editor). Whatever name you give it here is the name of the instance (for example: "UIView42"). In your UIViewController's viewDidLoad method you can then link it as "instance.delegate = self" ("UIView42.delegate = self")

Answer (score 1):

`performSegue` is part of `UIViewController`. `UIView` cannot perform segue. Try to call this method from an associated `UIViewController`

Comment: How can I call it? I have 2 different classes

Comment: Add a variable `viewController` to your class, which should perform segue. And before adding subview, set `viewController` to your view.
`xib.viewController = self;
self.view.addSubview(xib);`

Comment: Can you please describe the first part about `viewController`?

Comment: I've not tested, but I think you got the idea
https://gist.github.com/GRIM2D/5463fbc0417277c1d155

Comment: yes, I did it before your last comment, too. It does not perform anything =/

Comment: How can I do it with delegate?

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to learn delegation and although I haven't wrapped my head around it completely. I know what the code is all about. Here is a cheat sheet on how to make this happen:

**Goal**: To perform a function or pass back data from UIView to the UIViewController it's in.

**Example**: You have a UIViewController with a UIView in it, you want to press a button in the UIView and cause the UIViewController to perform a segue.

Disclaimer: This particular example is lame as you can wire up a button from the UIView straight to the UIViewController via storyboard, but you get idea.

To accomplish the example follow the steps:

**1.** In your UIView class you will want to write this (this is the **sender** class):

```
import UIKit //written for reference on file scope

// Define protocol outside of class
protocol SomeUIViewDelegate { 
    func segueFunction() //this function will be in your receiving class
}

class SomeUIView: UIView {

    //define the delegate as such:
    var delegate: SomeUIViewDelegate?

    //fake button press function I made for the tutorial
    func someButtonPress(){

        //this code goes wherever you want the delegate to "fire," like in this button press
        delegate?.segueFunction()

    }
}
```

**2.** In your UIViewController class you will want to write this (this is the **receiver** class):

```
import UIKit //written for reference on file scope

//state the class will conform to the delegate
class SomeUIViewController: UIViewController, SomeUIViewDelegate {

    //IMPORTANT: you must instantiate the SomeUIView class! 
    //use storyboard to right click drag and drop a line onto assistant editor, then name the instance 
    @IBOutlet weak var SomeUIViewNamedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       //set the classes delegate to itself in viewDidLoad
       SomeUIViewNamedInstance.delegate = self

    }

    //this is the function we defined in the protocol in SomeUIView class, it executes whenever you call it from the sender class
    func segueFunction() {

        //perform segue or whatever else you want
        //EXTRA CREDIT: You can pass data too from sender to receiver within the function parameters!!

    }

}
```

EDIT: Wanted to add this excellent article on delegation to this answer for curious minds. http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can call a segue to happen.

1. Create a segue in storyboard and give it a identifier.
2. When user click on the button you can invoke the segue to happen like following:

   ```
   self.storyboard(performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self))
   ```

Comment: `Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegueWithIdentifier'`

Comment: instead of using self.storyboard try creating an instance of the storyboard and use that instead.        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Main, bundle: nil);    storyboard(performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self))

Comment: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`. The same error